# can not run jbpm 7.13.0 and jboss 7 in same instance

Tags: java, jboss, jbpm

can not run jbpm 7.13.0 and jboss 7 in same instance.port 9990 is already used by admin console.how can i change the port of admin console for jbppm 7.13.0.

```
    15:05:15,714 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://192.168.10.109:9990
15:05:15,714 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 105254ms - Started 877 of 992 services (2 services failed or missing dependencies, 105 services are passive or on-demand)
15:05:15,923 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015871: Deploy of deployment "manageit.war" was rolled back with no failure message
15:05:15,924 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "cisms.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cisms" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cisms: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}
15:05:15,937 WARN  [org.exoplatform.portal.resource.MainResourceResolver] (MSC service thread 1-4) Cannot find servlet context module
15:05:15,939 WARN  [org.exoplatform.portal.resource.MainResourceResolver] (MSC service thread 1-4) Cannot find servlet context module
15:05:16,153 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment manageit.war in 229ms
15:05:16,174 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment cisms.war in 249ms
15:05:16,175 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cisms: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cisms: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

15:05:16,177 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cisms" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./cisms: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}}}
15:05:16,223 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `<jbpm server>/standalone/configuration` and modify the socket-binding-group section in standalone.xml to change the deafult http port bindings.

Eg:For changing http admin port from 9990 to 9992

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9992}"/>
    ........
<socket-binding-group>
```

OR You can specify a port offset while starting

Eg : standalone.bat -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=5

This will change all ports by 5. ie 9990 will become 9995